# How to fix an error in dll file

Tags: c++, assembly, dll

1) I'am trying to open the dll file with Hxd editor, but in the right side there is non-readeble text

2) so then I'am trying to fix this using xextool, but when I'am executing the dll file I get an error while reading the dll

What can I do?

Its a .dll packed by UPX 0.80 - 1.24 DLL -> Markus & Laszlo - I can't find this on google, anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: If you are expecting to fix compiled code with a hex editor, I'm guessing you should know *exactly* what you are doing. What is wrong with the DLL, and why can't you re-build it?

Comment: I get an error on xextool - error reading bfmod.dll, I've tried many tools on the internet by still no luck, first I need to decrypt the code, thats why I'am using xextool, and then look it in the hex editor, and save the changes, but I can't do it because of the error, also I'am getting this error on all the dlls in my computer when using xextool, why is that happening, because in the tutorials all is working

Comment: You couldn't find it on Google? Did you try "Markus & Laszlo" or "UPX"?

Comment: no didn't find it, unfortunaly

Comment: Try `vi, xemacs, or ultra edit` and open the file in hex mode.  You may need to decrypt it first, but now we talking the realm of not honorable hacking.

Comment: can you tell me why I get that error on reading the .dll or .xex file using xextool? its happening on all .dll files i am on windows

Comment: @TargetCoder [This](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) is the first hit on Google.

Comment: xextool is a tool for mucking about with .xex files (encrypted XBox 360 exes). It's unlikely to do anything useful with Windows DLLs. Are you *sure* you know what you're getting yourself into?

Comment: Yes I've tried it but no luck, after unpacking I get a file with "_" symbol added to the dll name, and I don't know what to do with it, it is not decrypted anyway

Comment: after opening it with IDA PRO I get assembly code, but how can I find there ip addreses numbers?

Answer (score 1):

In general, released code has no symbolic information.  When you open a released DLL and look at it with a hex editor you might be able to see text if the text is a string literal.

To see the assembly language, you need to open the DLL in a debugger or pass it to a tool that can convert the DLL executable code to assembly language.

Modifying an executable or DLL with a hex editor is difficult at best.  You can change constants easily and modify instructions.  However, to insert any new code or data increases the complexity of the operation. You may need to move code, and recalculate branch offsets and maybe change the addresses of where the instructions load data.

Usually, the best approach is to obtain the source for the DLL and rebuild it. Or submit a problem report to the source owner and wait for a new release.

The fact that you posted this issue shows that you don't have the experience to successfully modify a DLL.  So go the other route and rebuild it.

Comment: I need only to modify the ip address that is inside the dll, I 've tried to luck at ip addreses in the assembly editor, but didn't find it, using IDA PRO

Comment: IP addresses can be encoded in a number of ways, binary, or as text, or more likely here, a server name to use. What kind of connection is made to this server?

Comment: I don't know that, I have only the dll file, I don't know which editor or program to use to solve this, which one can you recommend?